# Curl Virtual Merchant

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to set up Virtual Merchant by curl call.

```
$url = 'https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/process.do';

$request = curl_init($url); // initiate curl object
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); // use HTTP POST to send form data
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response.
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            $post_response = curl_exec($request); // execute curl post and store results in $post_response
            curl_close ($request); // close curl object

            print_r($post_response);die();
```

fields are setup propertly.

When I execute this code it redirect me first to blank page, then refresh but after refresh I have requested parameters like:
perfect-process-status.php?ssl_email=&ssl_status=TEST+MODE&ssl_cvv2_response=P&... and so on ...

var_dump result (before redirect)

string(1504) "
"

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and see what that gives you.

Comment: Pretty sure `cURL` doesn't redirect you, but the response does?

Comment: string(1504)... So you have data. But, I think it's xml, so you dont see anything. try to echo htmlspecialchars($post_response); or just press <ctrl> + <u> for view source

Comment: htmlspecialchars($post_response) works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this: curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

Answer (score 0):

I'am worked on virtual merchant gateway.

```
$url = 'https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/process.do';
$fields = array(
'ssl_merchant_id'=>'Enter the virtual merchant id',
    'ssl_user_id'=>'Enter the user id',
    'ssl_pin'=>'Enter the pin number',
    'ssl_show_form'=>'false',//if it is true Converge virtual merchant send one form.
    'ssl_transaction_type'=>'ccsale',
    'ssl_avs_address'=> 'Enter ur address',
    'ssl_avs_zip'=> 'Enter ur zip code',
    'ssl_email'=>'Enter ur email id',
    'ssl_first_name'=>'Enter ur first name',
    'ssl_last_name'=>'Enter the last name',
    'ssl_state'=>'Enter state',
    'ssl_amount'=>'Enter amount details',
    'ssl_card_number'=>'Enter Account card number',//For Dummy card number: '5123456789012346'  
    'ssl_exp_date'=>'Enter Expire date of card',//For Dummy expire date: '0522'
    'ssl_cvv2cvc2'=>'Enter cvc number',//Dummy cvv number: '100'
    'ssl_invoice_number'=>'Enter Invoice number',       
);
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
//open curl session
$ch = curl_init();
//begin seting curl options
//set URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//set method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//set post data string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//these two options are frequently necessary to avoid SSL errors with PHP
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
//perform the curl post and store the result
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close the curl session
curl_close($ch);}
```

You must add values to $fields_string, without values then it will show empty. if you to know more Virtual merchant goto: [here](https://www.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchant/download/developerGuide.pdf). in that pdf also having ***Php Sample code***.